# how to automatically delete patterns of the type [*] with vim

Tags: vim, vi

I have a text document with a bunch of references [1], [2], ..., [70], etc. How can I use vi to automatically delete them? That is, delete everything that matches the pattern: [*].

Answer (score 3):

try running this command:

```
:%s/\[[0-9]\+\]//g
```

It finds all patterns of numbers in brackets `\[[0-9]\+\]`, and substitutes `:s` all occurances `g` on all lines `%` with an empty string.

In order to run it, start out in normal mode, and type the command above, including the colon.

Comment: you're wrong, you shall not backslash `+` as then it is matching `[4+]` but not `[42]`

Comment: @zmo: No, _you're_ wrong; on a fresh Vim 7.4 install this works fine. Note that Vim has different escape rules from other regex engines.

Comment: It's a weird thing about vim syntax that some special characters are backslashed but not others. In this case you do have to backslash the plus or it will match a literal plus. See `:help /\+`

Comment: and to make things even simpler, you can change that behaviour using `\v` at the start of your regex

Comment: Actually, whether `+` needs to be escaped or not depends on the "very magic" flag, see `:help /magic`.

Answer (score 1):

just to develop @user156213's very good answer:

```
:
%     —→ make the regex match the whole file range (from line 1 to last line)
s     —→ use the substitute regex command
/     —→ separator for the regex to match against
\[    —→ look for a [ character on a line
[0-9] —→ look for any digit
\+    —→ look for 1 or more occurence of thee the previous pattern
\]    —→ look for a ] character
/     —→ separator between the match regex and the replacement string
/     —→ end of the replacement string (i.e.: nothing)
g     —→ apply the match multiple times each line
```

Here's the same regex shown as an automaton:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

```
%s/\[[^]]*\]//g
```

or non-greedy:

```
%s/\[.\{-}\]//g
```

both will do what you wanted : `delete everything that matches the pattern: [*].`

Comment: @SagarJain which part you don't get?

Comment: .\{-}\
Why did you escape { but not }

Comment: @SagarJain `:h /\{` you will see